# How to update serialized data in the user meta data

Tags: custom-field, updates, user-meta

In my wp_usermeta table I have a field called "wp_s2member_custom_fields"

In it is stored this value:

a:2:{s:6:"alumni";s:3:"Yes";s:19:"donations_collected";s:2:"10";}

I am trying to use:

update_user_meta( $team_member_id, wp_s2member_custom_fields, $meta_value)

To update "donations_collected" from 10 to 11.

What should I put in $meta_value?

Answer (score 7):

Thats just PHP [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) array notation. You would get that same result by this code:

```
$meta_value = array(
    'alumni' => 'Yes',
    'donations_collected' => '10'
    );

update_user_meta( $team_member_id, 'wp_s2member_custom_fields', $meta_value);
```

So if you want to then change the donations_collected value to 11:

```
$meta_value = get_user_meta( $team_member_id, 'wp_s2member_custom_fields', true );    
$meta_value['donations_collected']++;
update_user_meta( $team_member_id, 'wp_s2member_custom_fields', $meta_value);
```