# How do I update a specific object in an array, in user meta?

Tags: array, user-meta

I have this array, below, to set custom user meta (`lh_userbadges`) in `user_meta` but I'm not exactly sure how to update just parts of the array later on...

```
$lh_user_badges = array(
    'lh_userbadge_comments25' => '0',
    'lh_userbadge_comments50' => '0',
    'lh_userbadge_comments75' => '0',
    'lh_userbadge_comments100' => '0',
    'lh_userbadge_comments150' => '0',
    'lh_userbadge_submited' => '0',
    //etc.
);
update_user_meta($user_id, 'lh_userbadges', $lh_user_badges);
```

From what I gathered in other stack overflow questions ([How to update serialized data in the user meta data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27513/how-to-update-serialized-data-in-the-user-meta-data) is a good example BUT it just increments, which I don't want. I want to set a specific number just once.), I think it something along these lines but, I'm just not sure....

```
$meta_value = get_user_meta($user_id, 'lh_userbadges', false);
$meta_value['lh_userbadge_comments25']  //....?
```

So, for example, I just want to update the object `lh_userbadge_comments25` from `lh_userbadges` from 0 to (lets say) 25, how would I do that? I think I'm on the right track with that 2nd part of code but I do not know...

Any ideas? **Also, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but I figured this would save database clutter if I did it in this format rather than each type being it's own meta item.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just assign a new value to the `1h_userbadge_comments25` key.

Like so...

```
<?php
$meta_value = get_user_meta($user_id, 'lh_userbadges', false);
// just assign this key a new value
$meta_value['lh_userbadge_comments25'] = 25;
```

Then just save it again.

```
<?php
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'lh_userbadges', $meta_value );
```

Whether or not storing all of those values as an array is the correct way to do this is really up to you. Do you need to do a lot of changing around like this?  Do the all these values make sense together? Without knowing more about what you're doing, that's a hard question to answer.

Comment: Thanks Christopher for the advance. That works perfect! And based on what I'm doing they do all make sense together so I think this is the best route to go. Thanks again! :D